# what is the solution for this equation : $2^x-6(2)^{-x}=6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

what is the solution for this equation : $2^x-6(2)^{-x}=6$

I couldn't even make one step ! :(

I thought to use logarithms here but it wouldn't be useful .. it would make it more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2^x-6(2)^{-x}=6$$
$$2^x-6/2^{x}=6$$
$$(2^x)^2-6\cdot2^{x}-6=0$$
$$2^x=\frac{6\pm\sqrt{60}}{2}$$
because $2^x>0$
$$2^x=\frac{6+\sqrt{60}}{2}=3+\sqrt{15}\iff x=\log_2{(3+\sqrt{15})}$$

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $y := 2^x$ and use $2^{-x} = 1/y$. Then solve for $y$ (how?) and solve the result for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$2^x - \dfrac{6}{2^x} = 6$.

Let $t = 2^x$.  This is now a simple equation:

$t - \dfrac{6}{t}=6$.

And an obligatory reminder to ignore any negative solutions, since you are working with real numbers.

Comment: why should i ignore negative solutions ?

Comment: If $t$ is negative, then $2^x$ will be negative for some real $x$, which is not possible.